# Trying to insert image into database. Getting Notice: Undefined index

Tags: php

I'm trying to insert an image into a database but I'm getting errors like this:

> Notice: Undefined index: product_image in C:\xampp\htdocs\inv-\product_action.php on line 18
>   Notice: Undefined index: product_image in C:\xampp\htdocs\inv-\product_action.php on line 19
>   Notice: Undefined index: product_image in C:\xampp\htdocs\inv-\product_action.php on line 20

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <label>Material Image:</label>
    <input type="file" name="product_image" accept="image/*" class="form-control" required />
  </div>
```

```php
if(isset($_POST['btn_action']))
{
    if($_POST['btn_action'] == 'load_brand')
    {
        echo fill_brand_list($connect, $_POST['category_id']);
    }
    if($_POST['btn_action'] == 'Add')
    {
            $imgFile = $_FILES['product_image']['name'];
            $tmp_dir = $_FILES['product_image']['tmp_name'];
            $imgSize = $_FILES['product_image']['size'];


            $upload_dir = 'images/'; // upload directory

            $imgExt = strtolower(pathinfo($imgFile,PATHINFO_EXTENSION)); // get image extension

            // valid image extensions
            $valid_extensions = array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif'); // valid extensions

            // rename uploading image
            $product_image = rand(1000,1000000).".".$imgExt;

            // allow valid image file formats
            if(in_array($imgExt, $valid_extensions)){           
                // Check file size '5MB'
                if($imgSize < 5000000)              {
                    move_uploaded_file($tmp_dir,$upload_dir.$product_image);
                }
                else{
                    $errMSG = "Sorry, your file is too large.";
                }
            }
            else{
                $errMSG = "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";        
            }


        $query = "
        INSERT INTO product (category_id, brand_id, product_date, product_time, product_name, product_description, product_quantity, product_unit, product_base_price, product_enter_by, product_status, po_no, or_no, vr_no, pc_no, supplier) 
                    VALUES (:category_id, :brand_id, :product_date, :product_time, :product_name, :product_description, :product_quantity, :product_unit, :product_base_price, :product_enter_by, :product_status, :po_no, :or_no, :vr_no, :pc_no, :supplier)
        ";
        $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
        $statement->execute(
            array(
                ':category_id'          =>  $_POST['category_id'],
                ':brand_id'             =>  $_POST['brand_id'],
                ':product_date'         =>  $_POST["product_date"],
                ':product_time'         =>  $_POST["product_time"],                     
                ':product_name'         =>  $_POST['product_name'],
                ':product_description'  =>  $_POST['product_description'],
                ':product_quantity'     =>  $_POST['product_quantity'],
                ':product_unit'         =>  $_POST['product_unit'],
                ':product_base_price'   =>  $_POST['product_base_price'],
                ':po_no'                    =>  $_POST['po_no'],
                ':or_no'                    =>  $_POST['or_no'],
                ':vr_no'                    =>  $_POST['vr_no'],
                ':pc_no'                    =>  $_POST['pc_no'],                
                ':supplier'                 =>  $_POST['supplier'],
                ':product_enter_by'     =>  $_SESSION["user_id"],           
                ':product_status'       =>  'active',
                ':product_image'        =>  $product_image
            )           
        );
```

The lines 18 is  `$imgFile = $_FILES['product_image']['name'];`
The lines 19 is  `$tmp_dir = $_FILES['product_image']['tmp_name'];`
The lines 20 is  `$imgSize = $_FILES['product_image']['size'];`

my PHP product form

```
<?php
//product.php

include('database_connection.php');
include('function.php');

if(!isset($_SESSION["type"]))
{
    header('location:login.php');
}



include('header.php');


?>
        <span id='alert_action'></span>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading panel-heading-custom">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-8 col-xs-6">
                                <h3 class="panel-title">Product Table</h3>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6" align='right'>
                                <button type="button" name="add" id="add_button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs">Add</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="row"><div class="col-sm-12 table-responsive">
                            <table id="product_data" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                                <thead><tr>
                                    <th>ID</th>
                                    <th>Category</th>
                                    <th>Brand</th>                              
                                    <th>Product Name</th>
                                    <th>Quantity</th>
                                    <th>Enter By</th>
                                    <th>Status</th>
                                    <th></th>
                                    <th></th>
                                    <th></th>
                                </tr></thead>
                            </table>
                        </div></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

<!-- FORM -->
        <div id="productModal" class="modal fade">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <form method="post" id="product_form">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add Product</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                         <div class="row">

                     <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Date</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="product_date" class="form-control" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d"); ?>" id="date" readonly />
                            </div>
                            </div>


                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Time</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="product_time" class="form-control" value="<?php date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Hong_Kong"); echo date("h:i:sa"); ?>" id="time" readonly />
                            </div>
                            </div>
                    </div>


                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Select Category</label>
                                <select name="category_id" id="category_id" class="form-control" required>
                                    <option value="">Select Category</option>
                                    <?php echo fill_category_list($connect);?>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Select Brand</label>
                                <select name="brand_id" id="brand_id" class="form-control" required>
                                    <option value="">Select Brand</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>



                        <div class="row">       
                            <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-6">                          
                                <label>Enter Product Name</label>
                                <input type="text" name="product_name" id="product_name" class="form-control" required />
                        </div>

                         <div class="form-group">                       
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <label>Material Image:</label>
                            <input type="file" name="product_image" accept="image/*" />                 
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Product Description</label>
                        <textarea name="product_description" id="product_description" class="form-control" rows="5" required></textarea>
                        </div>


                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Quantity</label>
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <input type="text" name="product_quantity" id="product_quantity" class="form-control" required pattern="[+-]?([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+" /> 
                                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                                        <select name="product_unit" id="product_unit" required>
                                            <option value="">Select Unit</option>
                                            <option value="Bags">Bags</option>
                                            <option value="Bottles">Bottles</option>
                                            <option value="Box">Box</option>
                                            <option value="Dozens">Dozens</option>
                                            <option value="Feet">Feet</option>
                                            <option value="Gallon">Gallon</option>
                                            <option value="Grams">Grams</option>
                                            <option value="Inch">Inch</option>
                                            <option value="Kg">Kg</option>
                                            <option value="Liters">Liters</option>
                                            <option value="Meter">Meter</option>
                                            <option value="Nos">Nos</option>
                                            <option value="Packet">Packet</option>
                                            <option value="Rolls">Rolls</option>
                                            <option value="Pcs">Pcs</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>


                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Price</label>
                                <input type="text" name="product_base_price" id="product_base_price" class="form-control" required pattern="[+-]?([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+" />
                            </div>

                        <div class="form-group">                            
                        <label>Receipt Details</label>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" name="po_no"  class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Purhase Order No." id="po_no"  />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" name="or_no" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Official Receipt No."  id="or_no" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" name="vr_no" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Voucher Receipt No." id="vr_no" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" name="pc_no" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Petty Cash No." id="pc_no" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>  
                        </div>


                            <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Supplier</label>
                                        <select name="supplier" class="form-control" id="supplier" required>
                                        <option value="" >~ Select Supplier ~</option>
                                        <?php 

                                        include('connect-db.php');
                                         $query = "SELECT * FROM `supplier`";
                                         $result = mysqli_query($DBcon, $query);
                                         while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)):;
                                        ?>
                                        <option value="<?php echo $row['supplier_name']; ?>"><?php echo $row['supplier_name']; ?></option>
                                        <?php endwhile; ?>
                                        </select>
                            </div>


                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <input type="hidden" name="product_id" id="product_id" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="btn_action" id="btn_action" />
                            <input type="submit" name="action" id="action" class="btn btn-info" value="Add" />
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="productdetailsModal" class="modal fade">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <form method="post" id="product_form">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Product Details</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <Div id="product_details"></Div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">

                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
<!-- FORM -->
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var productdataTable = $('#product_data').DataTable({
        "processing":true,
        "serverSide":true,
        "order":[],
        "ajax":{
            url:"product_fetch.php",
            type:"POST"
        },
        "columnDefs":[
            {
                "targets":[7, 8, 9],
                "orderable":false,
            },
        ],
        "pageLength": 10
    });

    $('#add_button').click(function(){
        $('#productModal').modal('show');
        $('#product_form')[0].reset();
        $('.modal-title').html("<i class='fa fa-plus'></i> Add Product");
        $('#action').val("Add");
        $('#btn_action').val("Add");
    });

    $('#category_id').change(function(){
        var category_id = $('#category_id').val();
        var btn_action = 'load_brand';
        $.ajax({
            url:"product_action.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{category_id:category_id, btn_action:btn_action},
            success:function(data)
            {
                $('#brand_id').html(data);
            }
        });
    });

    $(document).on('submit', '#product_form', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#action').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        var form_data = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url:"product_action.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:form_data,
            success:function(data)
            {
                $('#product_form')[0].reset();
                $('#productModal').modal('hide');
                $('#alert_action').fadeIn().html('<div class="alert alert-success">'+data+'</div>');
                $('#action').attr('disabled', false);
                productdataTable.ajax.reload();
            }
        })
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.view', function(){
        var product_id = $(this).attr("id");
        var btn_action = 'product_details';
        $.ajax({
            url:"product_action.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{product_id:product_id, btn_action:btn_action},
            success:function(data){
                $('#productdetailsModal').modal('show');
                $('#product_details').html(data);
            }
        })
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.update', function(){
        var product_id = $(this).attr("id");
        var btn_action = 'fetch_single';
        $.ajax({
            url:"product_action.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{product_id:product_id, btn_action:btn_action},
            dataType:"json",
            success:function(data){
                $('#productModal').modal('show');
                $('#category_id').val(data.category_id);
                $('#brand_id').html(data.brand_select_box);
                $('#brand_id').val(data.brand_id);
                $('#product_name').val(data.product_name);
                $('#product_description').val(data.product_description);
                $('#product_quantity').val(data.product_quantity);
                $('#product_unit').val(data.product_unit);
                $('#product_base_price').val(data.product_base_price);
                $('#product_tax').val(data.product_tax);
                $('.modal-title').html("<i class='fa fa-pencil-square-o'></i> Edit Product");
                $('#product_id').val(product_id);
                $('#action').val("Edit");
                $('#btn_action').val("Edit");
            }
        })
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.delete', function(){
        var product_id = $(this).attr("id");
        var status = $(this).data("status");
        var btn_action = 'delete';
        if(confirm("Are you sure you want to change status?"))
        {
            $.ajax({
                url:"product_action.php",
                method:"POST",
                data:{product_id:product_id, status:status, btn_action:btn_action},
                success:function(data){
                    $('#alert_action').fadeIn().html('<div class="alert alert-info">'+data+'</div>');
                    productdataTable.ajax.reload();
                }
            });
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    });

});
</script>
<?php include('footer.php'); ?>
```

Comment: What does your HTML look like?

Comment: i want to insert image but It's not working im so sleepy searching for answer help me sir to solved this problem thank you

Comment: The rest is working fine only the image is not adding and i get 3 errors

Comment: Are you using an HTML `<form>`? If so, please include that code in your question.

Comment: It looks like your `<form>` needs `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. See [What does enctype='multipart/form-data' mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean).

Comment: im using php + html sir i have edit my question and uploaded my php form please check sir ty

Comment: @showdev sir I change my moethod form to like that and still got same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your form input's **name**:

```
<input type="file" name="product_image">
```

This error input the name "product_image" no exist.

and the form's **enctype**:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Answer (score 0):

its working now isr

```
            <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="product_form">
```

this is the answer thanks for solving my problem my query was fine so this is my real problem haha sorry guys im beginner